# Why offsetof returns a size_t instead of an uintptr_t?

Tags: c, pointers, c99

I noticed my implementation of offsetof:

```
#define offsetof(st, m) ((size_t)&(((st *)0)->m))
```

Returns a `size_t`, but I think it should be `uintptr_t` instead because the value of offsetof will be used most likely to increment a pointer.

I have this function:

```
int flash_seek(intptr_t offset32, int whence);
```

It moves the internal pointer of the FLASH to another location. So `offset32` is an offset. If I want to move my pointer from the offset of a structure:

```
flash_seek(offsetof(foo_t, bar), SEEK_CUR);
```

I get a warning because `uintptr_t` is not the same type as `size_t`. How should I correct this if I won't want to add a cast?

Comment: Perhaps then it is your function that has the wrong signature :-)

Comment: `size_t` is type for count, `uintptr_t` is type for position. It would not make sense for `offsetof` to return latter, no matter how it is implemented.

Comment: If on POSIX and you are after a file offset use `off_t` as defined by `<fcntl.h>` / `<sys/types.h>`

Comment: As a sidenote: It seems that you are using structures to store/read data on flash. This doesn't scale as well as doing proper serialization. Whenever you need to use `offsetof`, you should reconsider your design. Aim to minimize the reliance on structure layout.

Comment: `uintptr_t` is a type for pointer conversion, not arithmetic. If you'd like to think of the offset as a difference of addresses, you should use `prtrdiff_t`.

Comment: `offsetof(type, member)` expands to an integer constant expression of type `size_t` according to the C specification, so your implementation's version is correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`size_t` is an unsigned integral type that can hold the size of the largest object on your system.

That makes it the perfect candidate to hold what may be the offset of the last member in what is possibly the largest structure on your system.

It's also required to be defined on any conforming implementation of the C standard library. `uintptr_t` is optional.

A `uintptr_t` is also designed to hold addresses converted to integral values. It's to hold an absolute location, not an offset from some unspecified location. Furthermore, the standard imposes no requirement about how the mapping between `address->integral value->address` is to be done. It only requires that the address is the same on both ends.

The answer to *why* mainly boils down to `size_t` and `uintptr_t` being abstractions for completely different things, where the former is *required* to be defined.

Comment: Another point about `uintptr_t` is that it is only guaranteed to hold the integer cast of a pointer. Nowhere does the C standard guarantee that a pointer has to be an integer, only that casting to an integer and back again conserves the value.

Comment: @JeremyP: Does the Standard actually guarantee that casting a pointer to an integer and back conserves the value, or only that it yields a pointer which *compares equal* to the original?  It's possible for pointers to compare equal without being usable to access the same objects (a "just past" pointer may compare equal to a pointer to an object, but would only be usable for accessing preceding objects); the Standard doesn't say whether a recast uintptr_t can be used in any way that same-type pointers to which it compare equals could be used.

Comment: @supercat The standard doesn't guarantee that casting a pointer to an integer is even possible. The behaviour in both directions is "implementation defined". It does however guarantee that, if `uintptr_t` exists, you can cast a `void*` to it and back again and the result will compare equal which is the same as having the same value. What does "equal" mean if not "has the same value"?

Comment: @JeremyP: Saying that two pointers "compare equal" means that applying the `==`operator to them would yield 1.  A compiler might assume that given `int a1[1],a2[1],*p1=a1+5,*p2=a2,x,y;` even if `p1` and `p2` happen to compare equal, operations on `p1[x]` can only affect `a1` and operations on `p2[x]` can only affect `a2`.  If `p1` or `p2` were converted to `void*`, then `uintptr_t`, and then a `uintptr_t` with the same numeric value were converted to `void*`, and back to `int* p3`, it's unclear whether `p3[0]` could access `a2[0]`, `p3[-1]` could access `a1[0]`, both, or neither.

Comment: @JeremyP: It's also unclear what the meaning is supposed to be if a pointer of a type other than `void*` is converted to a `uintptr_t`, or vice versa.  If such a construct has no meaning, there would be no reason for the Standard to allow it syntactically.  On most systems there would be no sensible reason for it to behave differently from a cast to `void*` followed by `uintptr_t` or vice versa, but compilers do a lot of things for which there's no sensible reason.

Comment: @supercat In your example, dereferencing `p1` is undefined behaviour. In fact p1 is probably technically indeterminate because it is 4 `ints` beyond the end of the array.

Comment: @supercat Also to return to the original point, do you not think that it would be bizarre if two pointers that compared equal did not have the same value. Wouldn't that mean the implementation's definition of equality is broken?

Comment: @JeremyP: Sorry--I started with 5-element arrays and shrunk them but failed to edit `*p1=a1+1;`.  In that case, accessing `p1[-1]` would have defined behavior even though accessing `p1[0]` would not.

Comment: @JeremyP: The Standard specifies certain cases in which the behavior of the equality operator is specified and some in which it is not.  Given `extern int a1[1]; int a2[1];`, for example, the Standard says that `a1+1` might compare equal to `a2`, but doesn't make clear that if they ever do so they will always do so.

Comment: @supercat but we are not in that situation. We are talking about  casting *one* pointer to a `uintptr_t` and back again. Furthermore, it only guarantees the behaviour for `void*`.

Comment: @JeremyP: If code has a "just-past" pointer for an object which also happens to point to the address of some other object, and it casts that pointer to void*, then uintptr_t, then void*, and then its original type, would anything in the Standard forbid an implementation from yielding a pointer to the second object instead of a just-past pointer to the first even when some actions (such as computing `ptr[-1]`) would have defined behavior with the just-past pointer but not with the pointer to the other object?